# Error while importing Curve/Arc Line feature in PostgreSQL?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I am facing a problem while importing/loading a feature class in a PostgreSQL data base through OSGeo4W.  The feature class has a Curve/Arc Line feature. But it's showing some problem. Below is the error report.:

```
Warning 1: Geometry to be inserted is of type Multi Curve, whereas the layer geo
metry type is Multi Line String.
Insertion is likely to fail
ERROR 1: COPY statement failed.
ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiCurve) does not match column type (MultiLineString)
CONTEXT:  COPY ewire, line 2, column wkb_geometry: "010B000000010000000109000000
050000000102000000030000000000005E44C7C6400000009CF0A3D3400000009028C7C6..."
```

Comment: It clearly says it's not a line feature. You'll have to convert it or change the expected geometry type in the database.

Comment: yes, your column is set up to receive multilinestring, not multicurve datatype. You'll either need to change the datatype of that column in the table, or do like @lynxlynxlynx says and convert it but I honestly have never heard of that datatype. I don't think that's a native PostGIS type.

Comment: @Matt yup, [it is supported](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#EWKB_EWKT), and rather natively as a PostGIS own addition to the OGC Simple Feature Spec.